# phpMyAdmin logs out times out (Ubuntu Maverick) "config.inc.php" and "php.ini (cgi)" changed!

Tags: timeout, phpmyadmin, logout

phpMyAdmin 3.3.7deb2build0.10.10.1

php5-cgi 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1

/etc/phpmyadmin/**config.inc.php** edited:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'phpmyadmin_logs_out';  
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400; // 24 h
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $cfg['LoginCookieValidity']);
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

/etc/php5/cgi/**php.ini** edited (cli too):

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

full PMA conf> http://shorttext.com/i2gfzmyor0r

can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is the problem? Does phpMyAdmin time out when logging in or does your session time our while you're doing stuff, because Cookie Validity only has to do with the latter.

Comment: Logs out when idle. Settings above used to work on Ubuntu 10.04, no longer.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the php.ini of the virtual host:
/var/www/vhosts/system/%host_name%/etc/php.ini
you can check the value with phpinfo():
session-> local value for session.gc_maxlifetime